# Click twice on icon doesn't close dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going mad here.

I have a search icon. If the user clicks on it, a dropdown is opened. If he/she clicks outside of the element, it closes the dropdown. My problem is that I want to close it if the user clicks again on the icon, but this part doesn't work. I guess the problem is the event.stopPropagation.

I have the following js code:

```
$('.mobile-search').on('click', function(event){
                $('.oe_searchview').show().css('margin-bottom', '15px');
                if ($('.oe-right-toolbar').length) {
                        viewOptions.hide();
                    }
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation() // stops bubbling
                // hide search if user clicks outside of the search button
                $('html').on('click.search', function (ev) {
                if (!$(ev.target).parents('.oe_searchview').length && !$(ev.target).parents('.oe-search-options').length) { // if the click's parent has no .oe_searchview class then hide
                    $('html').off('click.search');
                    searchField.hide();
                } else if ($(ev.target).parents('.mobile-search').length) {
                    searchField.hide();
                }
                }); 
            });
```

HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 active-app-title">
   <h2 class="hidden-xs">OPPORTUNITIES</h2>
   <div class="btn btn-primary"><div class="ripple" style="width: 100%; height=100%;">Create</div> </div>
   <span>or</span>
   <div class="btn btn-primary"><div class="ripple" style="width: 100%; height=100%;">Add new column</div></div>
   <div class="mobile-search">
   <a href=""><img src="/website/static/src/img/search-icon.png" alt="Search Again" class="search-icon"/></a>
   </div>
   <div class="mobile-views">
       <a class="flaticon-pause45" href="#"></a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search">
   <div class="oe_searchview form-control input-sm active">
       <div class="oe_searchview_search" title="Search Again">
          <img src="/website/static/src/img/search-icon.png" alt="Search Again" class="search-icon"/>
       </div>
       <div class="oe_searchview_facets">
          <div class="oe_searchview_input" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="oe_searchview_unfold_drawer" title="Advanced Search...">
          <img src="/website/static/src/img/arrow-down.png" alt="Search Again" class="arrow-down-icon"/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="oe-search-options btn-group">
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Filters</button>
       </div>
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm oe-groupby-menu">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Group By</button>
       </div>
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Favorites</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="oe-right-toolbar">
       <div class="oe-view-manager-switch btn-group btn-group-sm">
           <span class="flaticon-pause45"></span>
           <span class="flaticon-list91"></span>
           <span class="flaticon-statistical"></span>
           <span class="flaticon-calendar160"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm novice in js so every help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your HTML too please.

Comment: Sure this `$('html').on('click.search', function (ev)` works? I've never seen it that way. Only this way: `$('html').on('click','.search', function (ev)`

Comment: I added the HTML code

Comment: it is event.namespacing, check this: http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: seems like you just need a simple if/else with a check to see if the dropdown is already visible?

Comment: But what is the problem with the else if block in the code? Why is it not executed?

Comment: It looks like you're setting the behaviour of a click on HTML in the search button behaviour. I would move this outside. Without more code I can't really figure out what's going on. Where are you declaring `searchField`? or `viewOptions`?

Comment: I declare them just before the mobile-search onClick.

Comment: also you are using event namespacing but you have no trigger for the event (in the code shown). You should have `trigger("click.search")` in there somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would approach it

```
// one behaviour for the search button
// this checks to see if the search button is visible, and if so, 
$('.mobile-search').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation() // stops bubbling

    if($('.oe_searchview').is(":visible")){
         // hide the search view
         $('.oe_searchview').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        // show the search view
        $('.oe_searchview').show().css('margin-bottom', '15px');
        if ($('.oe-right-toolbar').length) {
            viewOptions.hide();
        }
    }
});

// this second behaviour happens only 
// hide search if user clicks outside of the search button
$('html').on('click', function (ev) {
    if (!$(ev.target).parents('.oe_searchview').length && !$(ev.target).parents('.oe-search-options').length) { // if the click's parent has no .oe_searchview class then hide
        $('.oe_searchview').hide();
    } 
});
```